# IPMI device flooding /var/log/messages

Tags: syslog, ipmi

I've a CentOS 7.6 server being flooded by the IPMI device with a lot of errors on a specific sensor:

```
ipmievd: Unknown sensor ff
ipmievd: Get SEL Entry 1fe command failed: Requested sensor, data, or record not found
```

Any ideia on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple firmware upgrade solved the issue.

I only upgraded the BIOS completely forgetting about the IPMI firmware.

Link to the SuperMicro firmware downloads is here:
https://www.supermicro.com/support/bios/firmware.aspx